# Is there any open data business directory?

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, business

Is there any open data business directory ?

Ideally world wide.

I did tried to find but not much coming up, there are companies house UK data in csv file but not able to find anything worldwide and on massive scale

Answer (score 1):

The closest is probably [Open Corporates](https://opencorporates.com/), the data is not fully open data but you may be able to get what you need.

Comment: Thanks, it helps but I thought open data was always available free to download, but there seem to be no visible option for that on this website,

Comment: yeah, it's not really open data.